# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I created a countdown with Vue.js but I am having trouble showing the values I am getting. I have two components and I have read the single file component guide from Vue but I just don't seem to understand what it is that I am doing wrong. In the console I get the follow error:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "date". Expected Number, got String.

Though in my code it is defined as a number.

**app.js**

```
import './bootstrap.js';

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Vue from 'vue';

import CurrentTime from './components/CurrentTime';
import Bitbucket from './components/Bitbucket';
import InternetConnection from './components/InternetConnection';
import LastFm from './components/LastFm';
import PackagistStatistics from './components/PackagistStatistics';
import RainForecast from './components/RainForecast';
import Placeholder from './components/Placeholder';
import Youtube from './components/Youtube';
import ProjectCountdown from './components/ProjectCountdown';
import Countdown from './components/Countdown';


Vue.component('countdown', Countdown);

new Vue({

el: '#dashboard',

components: {
    CurrentTime,
    InternetConnection,
    Bitbucket,
    LastFm,
    PackagistStatistics,
    RainForecast,
    Placeholder,
    Youtube,
    ProjectCountdown,
    Countdown
},

created() {
    this.echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key: window.dashboard.pusherKey,
        cluster: 'eu',
        encrypted: true
    });
},
});
```

**ProjectCountdown.vue**

```
<template>
<div id="dashboard">
    <Countdown date="March 20, 2017 12:00"></Countdown>
    {{days}}
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Grid from './Grid';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Countdown from './Countdown';

export default {

components: {
    Grid,
    Countdown,
},

props: {
    grid: {
        type: String,
    },
},

data() {
    return {

    }
}
}



// Vue.filter('two_digits', function (value) {
//     if(value.toString().length <= 1)
//     {
//         return "0" + value.toString()
//     }
//     return value.toString();
// });
</script>
```

**Countdown.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    {{ seconds }}
</div>
</template>


<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
export default {

props: {
    date: {
        type: Number,
        coerce: str => Math.trunc(Date.parse(str) / 1000)
    },
},
data() {
    return {
        now: Math.trunc((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
    }
},
ready() {
    window.setInterval(() => {
        this.now = Math.trunc((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    },1000);


},
computed: {
    seconds() {
        return (this.date - this.now) % 60;
    },
    minutes() {
        return Math.trunc((this.date - this.now) / 60) % 60;
    },
    hours() {
        return Math.trunc((this.date - this.now) / 60 / 60) % 24;
    },
    days() {
        return Math.trunc((this.date - this.now) / 60 / 60 / 24);
    },
},
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

As the error is saying, It is coming from this line:

```
<Countdown date="March 20, 2017 12:00"></Countdown>
```

You are passing `date` as String, while in props there is validation for it being an Number. Here   is your validation:

```
props: {
    date: {
        type: Number,
        coerce: str => Math.trunc(Date.parse(str) / 1000)
    },
},
```

I think in the new project you are using vuejs2, where coerce option has been [removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#coerce-Prop-Option-removed). As stated [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#coerce-Prop-Option-removed) you can use a computed property like following:.

```
props: {
    date: {
        type: Number
    },
},
computed: {
   modifiedDate: function(){
       return Math.trunc(Date.parse(this.date) / 1000)
   }
}
```

You can use the `modifiedDate` now instead of `date`.

Comment: I know, but on my other project when importing the Vue.js library and having a file called vue.js I do the exact same thing, it works there, that is why I don't understand why it doesn't work here with the exact same code.

Comment: do I now need to change my other computed methods?

Comment: No, you just to add this new method, others will not get affected unless you are using `date` variable there, if yes, than you might see if you should use `modifiedDate ` there.

Comment: as you can see in my computed properties I am using the date variable in all the functions, for example: `seconds() {
        return (this.date - this.now) % 60;
    },`

Comment: You can just start using `this,modifiedDate` there in those methods/computed properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137745/discussion-between-lucafraser-and-saurabh).

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing wrong with Vue. The issue is in your code.

You declared date as number (btw. why?) and then you are passing string...

Declaration:

```
props: {
    date: {
        type: Number,
        coerce: str => Math.trunc(Date.parse(str) / 1000)
    },
},
```

Usage:
`<Countdown date="March 20, 2017 12:00"></Countdown>`

Using number to store date is not best idea (it can work but there are better ways).

Comment: A better way, like what?

Comment: Maybe Object and use MomentJS ?

Comment: The various types that you can define a prop as are listed here:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks
So the type Date would also be an option in this case.