# Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "type"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm passing an object to a component that is the modal and the modal is calling another component that is the form. The form receives this object. This object is changed, but I'm not changing the props directly, I add it to a variable inside the form component.

When I edit the value of the selects, it gives an error.

Form.vue - this is view/page

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid pb-3">
    <c-form :form="form" :editForm="true" @openModalEditForm="openModalEditForm" />
    <c-modal-edit-form :form="modal" v-if="modal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import cForm from '@/components/c-form.vue'
import CModalEditForm from '@/components/administrator/c-modalEditForm.vue'
export default {
  components: { cForm, CModalEditForm },
  name: 'AdministratorFormView',

  data(){
    return{
      form: {
        container: [
          // Card
          [
            // row
            [
              // Col
              {
                name: "title",
                label: "Título",
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: "Digite...",
                value: null,
                size: 8,
              },
            ],
            [
              {
                name: "title",
                label: "Título",
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: "Digite...",
                value: null,
                size: 8,
              },
              {
                name: "title",
                label: "Título",
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: "Digite...",
                value: null,
                size: 8,
              },
            ],
          ],

          // Card
          [
            // row
            [
              // Col
              {
                name: "title",
                label: "Título",
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: "Digite...",
                value: null,
                size: 8,
              },
            ],
            [
              {
                name: "title",
                label: "Título",
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: "Digite...",
                value: null,
                size: 8,
              },
              {
                name: "title",
                label: "Título",
                type: 'text',
                placeholder: "Digite...",
                value: null,
                size: 8,
              },
            ],
          ],
        ],
      },

      modal: null,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openModalEditForm(input){
      this.modal = {
        inputs: {
          input,
        }
      };

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$bvModal.show('modal-edit-form')
      }, 100);
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

c-modalFormEdit.vue

```
<template>
  <b-modal id="modal-edit-form" title="Editar campo" size="md">
    <c-form :form="form" :editInput="true" />

    <template #modal-footer="{ cancel }">
      <b-button variant="light" @click="cancel"> Sair sem salvar </b-button>

      <b-button class="btn btn-pet btn-outline-secondary" @click.prevent="save">
        Salvar
      </b-button>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
import cForm from '../c-form.vue'
export default {
  name: 'ComponenteModalEditForm',
  components: { cForm },
  props: {
    form: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  mounted(){
  },
}
</script>
```

c-form.vue

```
<div v-if="data.container">
      <b-card class="mt-3" v-for="(container, indexContainer) in data.container" :key="indexContainer">
        <b-card-text> Informações para logística </b-card-text>

        <hr>
        
        <div>
          <div class="row align-items-end w-100 position-relative" v-for="(row, indexRow) in container" :key="indexRow">
            <div :class="`col col-${row.length / 12} position-relative`" v-for="(input, index) in row" :key="index">
              <b-form-group :label="input.label" :class="`${editForm ? 'editForm__formGroup' : ''}`">
                <b-form-textarea v-if="input.type === 'textarea'" v-model="input.value" :placeholder="input.placeholder" rows="3" max-rows="5"></b-form-textarea>

                <b-form-select v-if="input.type === 'select'" v-model="input.value" :options="typeOptions"></b-form-select>

                <b-form-input v-else v-model="input.value" :type="input.type" :placeholder="input.placeholder" :required="input.required"></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>

              <!-- Buttons -->
              <div class="editForm__buttons" v-if="editForm">
                <b-button @click.prevent="openModalEditForm(input)" variant="transparent" class="p-0 mr-3">
                  <b-icon-pencil-square></b-icon-pencil-square>
                </b-button>
                <b-button @click.prevent="removeInput(input)" variant="transparent" class="p-0">
                  <b-icon-trash></b-icon-trash>
                </b-button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-auto">
              <b-button class="d-block mb-3" @click.prevent="" v-if="editForm">
                +
              </b-button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <b-button class="d-block mt-3 mx-auto" @click.prevent="" v-if="editForm">
          +
        </b-button>
      </b-card>
    </div>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ComponentForm',

  props: {
    form: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },

    editForm: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: false,
    },

    editInput: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      required: false,
    },
  },

  data(){
    return{
      data: this.form,

      typeOptions: ['text', 'select', 'textarea', 'number', 'email'],
      sizeOptions: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    openModalEditForm(input){
      this.$emit('openModalEditForm', input);
    },

    removeInput(input){

    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The error is always of the 'type' value. When I move in a select, it gives an error in it.

```
Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "type".
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid prop: type check failed for prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715136/invalid-prop-type-check-failed-for-prop)

Comment: not because the problem is in the value that it is passing. Mine is when I change the 'type' value that is inside the object

Comment: Is this code completed? Because this type of error only occurs when you have a validator function to validate the value of a particular prop. For example, if you have a prop named "type" and you defined inside the validator function what should be the value of this "type" prop? But I can't see any prop name "type" and any validator function in your provided code.